# Checking composition with inheritance constraints at compile time in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

I've got a question regarding the best-practices of Java inheritance & composition:

> Say you've got a Fruit which gets extended by Apple and Lemon.
>
> Next to these you also got a Basket that gets extended by AppleBasket
>   and LemonBasket.
>
> Fruits have a bidirectional one-to-many relationship with their
>   respective baskets, so Fruits have a basket, and baskets have a list
>   of fruits.

Now the thing I'd like to do is enforce the AppleBasket to only have Apples at compile time, and likewise for LemonBaskets. Similarly the Apple should only have an AppleBasket as property, and likewise for Lemons.

I've tried using generics, abstract methods and protected variables, yet I always find reasons not to go for a certain approach. It's important we don't break the SOLID principles, so for example the superclasses should contain the has-a and has-many properties to avoid code duplication and so on.

It's key to get compiler errors when someone tries to put a Lemon inside an AppleBasket and vice versa.

Cheers,
Andreas

Comment: Have you tried `Basket<T extends Fruit>` and `AppleBasket extends Basket<Apple>`?

Comment: What are your reasons for *not* using Generics?

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. I'm sure generics are necessary, but exactly how is unclear.

We'd need the two superclasses to be generic imo. Fruit<T extends Basket> with Apple extends Fruit<AppleBasket> and Basket<T extends Fruit> with AppleBasket<Apple>.

The thing is that I need to put the List of fruits & the Basket inside the superclasses as properties to avoid code duplication.

This makes the Fruit<T extends Basket> to have a Basket<T> and Basket<T extends Fruit> to have a List<Fruit<T>> as properties.

Comment: There is no need to do `Fruit<T extends Basket>` - why would you want the fruit to know about its basket??? A fruit is a fruit, whether it's in a basket or not. A basket contains fruits, and can keep track of what fruits it contains.

Comment: The fact that Fruit needs a reference to its Basket is a requirement, might not be too logical, but that's what the model has to be built like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find some useful information about more complex typing by googling for covariance and contravariance.

If you don't mind using Scala, which compiles to bytecode you can use with Java programs, Scala's gives you some nice syntax for doing this sort of thing (Java later):

```
class Fruit
class Basket[T <: Fruit ] {
    def addToBasket(fruit:T) =  {}
}

class Apple extends Fruit
class Lemon extends Fruit

class AppleBasket extends Basket[Apple]

val applebasket = new AppleBasket

applebasket.addToBasket(new Apple)

applebasket.addToBasket(new Lemon)
```

The last line of this code snippet gives the compile time error:

```
 $ scala Test.scala
C:\cygwin\home\user\Test.scala:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.Lemon
 required: this.Apple
applebasket.addToBasket(new Lemon)
                        ^
one error found
```

I've been playing with Scala so much lately I'm having trouble thinking about this in Java, but in Java I'd probably do something more like this:

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple extends Fruit{}
class Lemon extends Fruit{}
class Basket<T extends Fruit>{
    public void addToBasket(T foo) {}
}
class Blah {
    void doIt() {
        Apple a = new Apple();
        Basket b = new Basket<Apple>();
        b.addToBasket(a);
        Lemon l = new Lemon();
        b.addToBasket(l);
    }
}
```

The b.addToBasket(l) line gives the following compile time type error:

```
The method addToBasket(Apple) in the type Basket<Apple> is not applicable for the arguments (Lemon)
```

Another option that gives the same compile error (copying from comments to make it clearer):

```
//same definition of Fruit, Apple, and Basket, but with:
class AppleBasket extends Basket<Apple> {}
class Blah {
    void doIt() {
        Apple a = new Apple();
        Basket<Apple> b = new AppleBasket();
        b.addToBasket(a);
        Lemon l = new Lemon();
        b.addToBasket(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I can't use Scala, bound to the company's technologies :/
Anyways, the Basket in your response needs to be extended by AppleBasket and LemonBasket. Where would you put the "addToBasket" method then? In the subclasses or the superclass?

Comment: I think you get the same results with:
class AppleBasket extends Basket<Apple> {}
class Blah {
 void doIt() {
  Apple a = new Apple();
  Basket<Apple> b = new AppleBasket();
  b.addToBasket(a);
  Lemon l = new Lemon();
  b.addToBasket(l);
 }
}

... though you don't necessarily have to have a separate class to represent your AppleBasket.

But using this method, your applebasket still inherits addToBasket from the parent and is restricted on type.

Comment: added additional example from comment to the post for having AppleBasket as a separate class.